# POST call hangs without any response while checking the ColdFusion webservice

Tags: web-services, rest, coldfusion, cfc

I have created a REST service in ColdFusion with a POST. It takes input json from other application, checks them in my DB and returns the http status code. Simple.
Calling it from **RESTClient**-FireFox Plus from **POSTMAN**-Chrome, my application says it's success/failure depending upon authentication, but RESTClient hangs continuing to show the progress bar and the button Abort.

The GET works perfectly fine though. Can anyone please help?

GET - Works fine.
[image]

POST - Does not work.
[image]

Here is my webservice(cfc):

```
<cfcomponent rest="true" restpath="/AimsWeb"> <!--- REST Service--->

<cffunction name="AuthenticateUser" access="remote" httpmethod="POST"  returntype="void">

<!---- Defining Arguments--->
    <cfargument name="Username" type="string" required="Yes">
    <cfargument name="Password" type="string" required="Yes">
    <cfargument name="CustomerID" type="numeric" required="Yes">


<!---- Setting the Form Values (which we will get from AW+) and setting it to arguments passed--->
    <cfset Form.CustomerID = arguments.CustomerID>
    <cfset Form.Username = arguments.Username>
    <cfset Form.Password = arguments.Password>

<!--- Take input json, parse it and set in in a variable --->
<cfscript>
  record=deserializeJSON(
'{
"customerId": "#Form.CustomerID#",
"userName": "#Form.userName#",
"password": "#Form.Password#"
}'
);

this.customerid = record.customerId;
this.userName = record.userName;
this.password = record.password;
 </cfscript>
<cfdump var="#record#">


   <cfquery name="AllUsers" datasource="#Application.GomDatasource#">
        SELECT u.UserTypeID, u.UserID, u.CustomerID, u.UserName, u.Password, u.active, u.locked
        FROM tblUsers u
        WHERE
         u.username =  'swapnil'
   </cfquery>


<!--- This is to check whether provided parameters are valid by checking the same in the database --->
<cfset local.StatusStruct = StructNew()>
   <cflog text="in struct" type="information">


    <cfif AllUsers.RecordCount AND (AllUsers.Active EQ 0 OR AllUsers.locked EQ 1)>
        <cfheader statuscode="401" statustext="User Account is locked">
        <cflog text="account locked" type="information">
    <cfelse>

        <cfif this.customerid EQ "" OR this.username EQ "" OR this.password EQ "">
            <cfheader statuscode="400" statustext="Insufficient Input. Please provide Customer ID, UserName and Password">
            <cflog text="insufficient input" type="information">
        <cfelseif AllUsers.RecordCount AND (this.CustomerId EQ AllUsers.CustomerID AND this.username EQ AllUsers.UserName AND this.password EQ AllUsers.Password)>
            <cfheader statuscode="200" statustext="Success">
            <cflog text="success" type="information">
        <cfelseif AllUsers.CustomerID NEQ this.CustomerID>
            <cfheader statuscode="400" statustext="Customer Id doesn't exist">
            <cflog text="customer id not exist" type="information">
        <cfelseif AllUsers.UserName NEQ this.UserName>
            <cfheader statuscode="400" statustext="User not found">
            <cflog text="user name not found" type="information">
            <cfoutput>
            user name not found
            </cfoutput>
        <cfelseif AllUsers.Password NEQ this.password>
            <cfheader statuscode="400" statustext="Invalid Password">
            <cflog text="invalid password" type="information">
        </cfif>
    </cfif>

  </cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

Here is the JSON I am passing as a Body:

```
{
"customerId": 100,
"userName": "test",
"password": "xxxxx"
}
```

Comment: Test with [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) and tell us what is actually happening with the sent request.

Comment: Thanks @Alex: Issue resolved. Issue was with the JSON parsing.